# Remove decimals without rounding

Tags: c#, string, math, trim

I have some variable length decimal numbers for ex:
1.123, 
1.1234, 
12.12345,

I need only the first 4 decimals. I can't use Math.Round() because I do not want rounded numbers, I just want to trim it and keep only  first 4, like 1.1234, or 22.1234. Is there a way to accomplish this?
Thank you.

Comment: Is it for presentation? Just use the string.Format with "0.000".

Answer (score 3):

Multiply by 10000, store as integer to get rid off any remaining decimals. Divide by 10000.

Comment: Don't convert to int, instead use `Math.Truncate`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = number.ToString("n4");
```

check [Standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: This solution will round the number....